# Notepad++ Which regex or macro to bookmark next lines[of a previously searched word] without manually select them?

Tags: line, notepad++

**Which regex or macro to bookmark next lines without manually select them?**
I mean this:

1. **before**:
   [image]
2. **after**:
   [image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can't match a bookmark in a regex.

Comment: The Macro is F3, down arrow, Ctrl+F2

Comment: @user1391247 - please propose this as an asnwer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Macro is: <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>Down arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd>.

Comment: That's no macro, that's a sequence of keystrokes. ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Feel free to modify the Wiki answer.

Comment: Would `F2` (i.e. move to next bookmark) be better than `F3` (i.e. find next)?

Comment: Related but unanswered question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990205/notepad-doesnt-bookmark-all-marked-lines