# Notepad++ search with "Bookmark line" option doesn't bookmark all the lines that match a multi-line regex, but only the first one

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to filter everything from a log that belongs to a particular user.
With the following pattern, and the ". matches newline" option enabled, I can match everything that I am looking for, but when I ask Notepad++ to bookmark these line so I can copy them, something strange happens.

```
([^\n]+)userB(.+?)(?=([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}))
```

In front of line 2 and 8 I see a bookmark icon, but the lines: 3,4,5 and 9,10,11 are missing an icon, although they belong to the highlighted text.

Why does Notepad++ highlight the text, but doesn't place the bookmark correctly? And more importantly, how can I fix this?

Here is the log that I am using:

```
2015-03-02 11:28:44,993 INFO  application [http-0.0.0.0-8080-17]            userA     99:7 12345 some message
2015-03-02 11:28:45,468 WARN  application [http-0.0.0.0-8080-9]             userB     12:2  some message
extra information
    at some.classes.and.function(Filename.java:123)
    at some.classes.and.function(Filename.java:123)
2015-03-02 11:28:44,993 INFO  application [http-0.0.0.0-8080-17]            userA     99:7 12345 some message
2015-03-02 11:28:44,993 INFO  application [http-0.0.0.0-8080-17]            userA     99:7 12345 some message
2015-03-02 11:28:45,468 WARN  application [http-0.0.0.0-8080-9]             userB     12:2  some message
extra information
    at some.classes.and.function(Filename.java:123)
    at some.classes.and.function(Filename.java:123)
2015-03-02 11:28:44,993 INFO  application [http-0.0.0.0-8080-17]            userA     99:7 12345 some message
```

Comment: maybe you want to work on that title...

Answer (score 1):

The following will extract the information you want without using bookmarks and should work in Notepad++ version 6.9.1 onwards.
It assumes that the lines of extra information don't start with a digit.
It deletes the copied lines from the data file so work on a copy of the data file if you want to preserve it.
It is not very efficient because the switch tab command positions the cursor back at the start of a tab's text.
It duplicates the last match for userB. (A minor irritant!)

Description

```
1) Define shortcuts for switching to next & previous tabs
2) Open the data file with Notepad++
3) Open a new tab then go back to the data file tab
4) Define a macro `Cut User data. Paste in next tab`  
5) Run the macro `Cut User data. Paste in next tab` on the data file to `end of file`
  (It needs to be run once prior to running it in `Run a Macro Multiple Times`
  because of a quirk of Notepad++)
```

Method

1) `Settings` `Shortcut Mapper` `Main menu`
`Switch to previous document` = `Ctrl+Alt+Left`
`Switch to next document` = `Ctrl+Alt+Right`
`Close`

2) Open data file with Notepad++

3) `File` `New` `Ctrl+Alt+Left`

4) `Start Recording`
`Find` Find what: `.+  userB.+\r\n(\D.+\r\n)*`
 Search Mode = Regular expression
`Find Next` `Alt+F4`
`Ctrl+X` `Ctrl+Alt+Right`
`Ctrl+End` `Ctrl+V` `Ctrl+Alt+Left`
`Stop recording`
`Save Current Recorded Macro`
Name: `Cut User data. Paste in next tab` `OK`

5) `Macro` `Cut User data. Paste in next tab`
`Run a Macro Multiple Times`
Macro to run: `Cut User data. Paste in next tab`
Run until end of file = Yes
`Run` then when it has stopped `Cancel`

Answer (score 0):

(Editted to be an answer.)

At least in the current version of Notepad++ the macro halts while the switch dialog box appears when using the macro solution and switching tabs.

You must first go to settings, MISC., document switcher, and disable both check boxes. This is at least true in v7.6.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. This is not a forum, it's a Q&A site. I recommend to take a [tour] of the site. You've posted what should be an answer to the original question, but it isn't; it's a further request for help. This would be ok on a forum, but this is not a forum. When you post an answer, make sure you are addressing the problem in the question, and providing a solution to it. Once you have enough rep (15) you will be able to upvote other questions, otherwise you can ask a new question, maybe with a link to this one. But please do not post answers asking for help. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my post to propose a new, working, solution for this same problem. I appreciate your help.